# How to unlink a project from github

Tags: github

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Voi4.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJjib.png)

My project is messing up because of a (secret) code I deleted in my (now deleted) git repository

the story is I uploaded my project to github to ask for help but forgot about the secret .env codes. I decided to delete the repository and reuploaded the current one manually. Now I can't login to my project because of the deleted code even though I already added them in the VSC (image 1). I just wanna unlink the project to github

Are there any commands I can use to unlink the project from any git repository?

i deleted any and all git repositories and it's still connecting to them

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.